# check if last (or first) node with a child that has a particular value

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I'm transforming the following XML into an array of json objects with XSLT 1.0:

```
<a id="x">
    <active>Yes</active>
</a>
<a id="y">
    <active>No</active>
</a>
<a id="z">
    <active>Yes</active>
</a>
```

I only want to use the "a"'s that have "active" as "Yes". So far so good, I'm using:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(active/node(), 'Yes')">
```

Now the problem is that I need to output commas at the end of each object like so:

```
[
    {"id": "x"},
    {"id": "y"},
    {"id": "z"}
]
```

I can check if the node is the last with:

```
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
```

But if the last node has "active" set to "No", the previous one will output a comma, as it is not the last sibling, so I will have:

```
[
    {"id": "x"},
    {"id": "y"},
]
```

which is invalid json.. does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Basically I need to check if the current node is the last one with a child "active" set to "Yes". Alternatively, I could do the opposite and output the commas at the beginning of the node, except if this is the first node I'm writing.. but as I cant change the values of variables (seriously, why do they even call them variables in xslt? ..anyway), it sort of brings me back to my main problem again..

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position()` and `last()` functions don't necessarily refer to node positions within the XML tree but rather the position of the current node within the list of nodes selected by the current `for-each` or `apply-templates`.  So rather than processing *all* the `a` elements and checking the active flag with an `xsl:if`, you could do the filtering with a predicate at the `apply-templates`/`for-each` stage:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="a[active[contains(., 'Yes')]]" />
```

and now `position()` and `last()` will count only the "active" `a` elements rather than all of them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, that's even better :) I had actually thought about doing that way but didn't know exactly how to select it, and didn't know those functions referred to the selected list only

Answer (score 1):

you should nest if statement following:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(active, 'Yes')">
```

with

```
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::a[contains(active, 'Yes')]) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

rendering:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(active, 'Yes')">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::a[contains(active, 'Yes')]) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    Do something here
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: hmm thanks, but that doesn't work because even if t's inside the if, the position() will always return the actual position of node, so if the first node has "active" to "No", only the second will enter the IF, but position() will be 2, if you know what I mean?

Comment: I have edited my answer, this time I used the `count` function.

Comment: Eventually got it working mixing this answer with the next one as so: 
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::a[contains(active, 'Yes')]) &gt; 0">,</xsl:if> 
As I find it more logical to treat the commas at the end of the object..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying position you can query whether the current element has any subsequent siblings that meet your criteria.

```
<xsl:if test="count(following-siblings::a[active='Yes'])">,</xsl:if>
```

Example using the same technique:

http://www.xmlplayground.com/J7BZRz

Comment: hmm that makes sense but i get:
XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet():
    Invalid expression
    xsl:if : could not compile test expression 'following-siblings::a[active='Yes']'
XSLTProcessor::transformToXml():
    No stylesheet associated to this object

Comment: Eventually got it working mixing this answer with the next one as so:
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::a[contains(active, 'Yes')]) &gt; 0">,</xsl:if>
As I find it more logical to treat the commas at the end of the object.. Thank you!